# How to style my buttons to be at the bottom of my screen

Tags: css

Margin:bottom; isn't working and I need an alternative to this that can move all the buttons on my screen down. I am making a hangman game and I need to place my word to guess above the buttons. I cannot do that while the buttons are at the top. I need help to find a css command that can move the buttons down! Thanks so much!

Tried Margin:bottom; and vertical-align but neither worked... not sure why

```
/*these create my 26 alphabet buttons, and are essentially the thing I need to move downwards. */
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++){
   var etl = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   var let = String.fromCharCode(97+i);
   var tee = document.createTextNode(let);
   etl.appendChild(tee);
   document.body.appendChild(etl);
}

/* my css so far used to style my buttons along with my failed attempt to lower the buttons */

BUTTON { 
    margin: bottom;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9pt;
    outline: none;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", "Helvetica Ultra Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I expected the buttons to be at the bottom of the page, but they still stayed at the top.

Comment: `bottom` is not a valid value for `margin`. You might want to check out what the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property does. (It creates space around an element, rather than positioning that element)

Comment: You don't show any markup of your page structure to which you are adding the buttons. If the page contains a `<div>` with the other content, then `body.appendChild()` would place the buttons _after_ the div and they would just naturally appear at the bottom (below the div) simply due to the natural page flow.  Without showing your page structure any answer is a "best guess". `position:absolute` might indeed be the best solution, be we can't know that without more information. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/kxejmycv/) that does _nothing special_ to get the buttons at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set posution to fixed,

position: fixed; 
       bottom:0%;

**UPDATE** 
JS :

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV")
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++){
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");

   var let = String.fromCharCode(97+i);
   var tee = document.createTextNode(let);
   btn.appendChild(tee);
  btn.className = "buttonStyle";
  div.appendChild(btn);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(div);
```

CSS :

```
   div { 
  position: fixed; 
    bottom:0%;  
    }
        .buttonStyle {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9pt;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", "Helvetica Ultra Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                      }
```

Comment: Hello! I have the same issue as the other response. Only my final letter is moving to the bottom of the page [z]. I need all 26 letters to move.

Comment: you need to add a class attribute to your elements and applicate the css style to the class not to the element like .button {
 }

Comment: Okay I added a class to the buttons, but the outcome remains the same. The only letter that appears is still "z".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position to `absolute`.

```
button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
....
    }
```

Comment: I just tried that and it did move the button[s] to the bottom. The issue with your code is that it seems to only put the letter "z" [final element] at the bottom of the page. I believe your code is overwriting all instances of the element with the last one [z]. I need code that can move all my 26 letters to the bottom of the page, although I do appreciate the help!